# More logical setTimeout routine

Tags: javascript, timeout

I've created a simple read-along feature which highlights words at certain times. This is how I've done this so far:

```
            setTimeout(function(){ 
           $(".page3 > p >*:contains('The')").css('background',textColor)
            }, 400);

            setTimeout(function(){ 
               $('.word').css('background',transparent)
               $(".page3 > p >*:contains('dog')").css('background',textColor)
            }, 1000);

            setTimeout(function(){ 
              $('.word').css('background',transparent)      
              $(".page3 > p >*:contains('was')").css('background',textColor)
            }, 1700);
```

My question is would their be a better way of doing this?
I cannot use loops because each word and is different and the timings of the words are also very different.

EDIT: I had thought about perhaps using an array. The key could be the word and the value could be the timing (ms). I'm just not sure how I could do this? Would it need a loop of some form?

Comment: have u got a jsfiddle

Comment: I haven't. Is there anything you need me to explain in more detail?

Comment: does your code work - if so can we see it. i would split the string by spaces, but i don't know what you've done

Comment: you can simplify it slightly, but not too much. i would make the repetitive parts into stand-alone functions, and maybe condense the floating functions into object members, but you still need the function(){} overhead and the setTimeout interval each spec...

Comment: It does work but it's a massive project (Around 3000 lines of code in the JS) So It would be hard to separate and drop into JS Fiddle. Basically each word on a page is a different span, each with the class of 'word'. These timeouts run on the click of a button and the words start highlighting. (hence why i'm targeting each word by using 'contains'). Let me know if you need more detail

Comment: @dandavis I hadn't thought of putting the   $('.word').css('background',transparent)   into a named function so that's a start!

Answer (score 0):

here is a jsfiddle for you

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7ty15Lh8/2/)

```
changeWord('Lorem','text',1000);
```

Basically it can be solved with setTimeout implemented in a function, so you don't always have to write the same function over and over again.

i personally suggest to add classes to certain objects and use this class for the css. jquery css is not my fav :)